# Laptop goes to hibernation after 15 minutes of inactivity while plugged in

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, dll, charging

I have the a laptop, which is running on Windows 10 (22H2) (OS Build: 19045.2546) and I have been facing hibernation issue every 15-20 minutes when left idle, since today morning. This happens when the PC is on charge, and nothing happens when I keep it on battery power. Checking the Event Viewer showed me some errors which happened exactly before sudden shutting down of the PC. The error being reported was: `Autopilot.dll Error Was Reported on Windows.`

I tried finding out the solution for this error and it led to this page: [Autopilot.dll WIL error](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/autopilotdll-wil-error/9432c664-8a28-4aa9-8655-4a8db6508c17) .

There I found this link that had a tutorial to disable a Microsoft Service (along with caveats of disabling it): [Fix: Autopilot.dll WIL Error Was Reported on Windows](https://appuals.com/autopilot-dll-wil-error-was-reported/).

After disabling it, I checked if the fix is working or not. For the first time, I could get my computer up when left idle for more than 35 minutes (previously it was not the case).

However, after a restart, when I left my PC turned on with the PDF open and went to do something in another room and came back after 20 mins only to find that the PC was turned off. When I turned it on, it booted up and the PDF that I was reading before leaving, as well as all other windows were still there. However, the PC didn't go to sleep, as in that case the power LED would have been blinking. That is, it got itself to hibernation after 15 minutes of inactivity.

When I checked the event viewer, there was a Warning: `A command sent to the adapter has timed out. The adapter did not respond.` which originated from the source called BTHUSB, but I suspect this the least.

Now, I am confused as to how I should narrow down the problem to find out whether the hardware or the software is at fault. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

**Note:** I have checked if my system supports S3 or S0 by using `powercfg /a` which gave me the following in `cmd`, ruling out the possibility of this happening due to Modern Standby:

```
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S3)
    Hibernate
    Hybrid Sleep
    Fast Startup
```

Comment: Almost always a hardware issue. If windows crashes you will get a blue screen.

Comment: Is this always the case? Does all windows crashes accompany a BSOD?

Comment: @Sanu_012 - Correct

Comment: @Ramhound after digging more into this problem, I have noticed that the PC actually goes into hibernation after exactly 15 minutes of inactivity, that is, if I don't touch the mouse or the keyboard, or have no movie/video/song being played on the screen. I have updated the question accordingly. How do I prevent this from happening? Why is it so that it happens only if I leave the laptop idle and plugged-in? Why this does not happen if I keep the system idle on battery power?

Comment: @Sanu_012 - The behavior you describe, the state of applications being restored, is a feature of Modern Standby.  Microsoft is actively looking for feedback on an issue associated with Modern Standby. [Here](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1475685-windows-modern-standby-bug-reporting/) are instructions to collect helpful debugging information.

Comment: They are turning bugs into features. Pathetic. Welcome to the new world order. Thank you @Ramhound for saving the day. I thought my PC was ruined :| 
Windows and Bugs, name a more iconic duo, I will wait ;)

Comment: @Sanu_012 - Modern Standby (S0) is a solution to a problem caused by OEM(s) like Dell and HP choosing to NOT update the driver based S3 power state drivers. So while there might be something going on with your device Modern Standby, if that is the case, it's better than the alternative.

Comment: @Ramhound - I understand. Using the instructions given in your link, I have generated a sleep report and the time when system went into hibernation matches the time that I recorded which I thought to be a shut down. I hope MS find a better way to do these things, else I will need to learn how to use Linux :'(

Comment: @Sanu_012 - It does not sound like you really use Modern Standby. You can always just disable it.

Comment: @Ramhound, I guess what I am experiencing is not something related to Modern Standby. My device doesn't support S0 mode. Context added in the question. I guess this is related to something else.

Comment: You will have to contact MSI with regards to S3 driver issues.

Comment: Their support is very poor. Are there drivers available for S3? Under what category can I expect to find them - Utility/Firmware/Drivers/BIOS ? Can updating the BIOS help me with this problem?

Comment: `else I will need to learn how to use Linux :'( ` .. as much as I love Linux, the power management SUCKS.  You will not find an upgrade to this problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scrolling Forums and Search Engines the whole day, and discovering about the fancy Modern Standby, I went back again to the basics and started afresh.
This very thing led me to the solution which was pretty simple.

This seemed like a power management issue, as soon as I was able to rule out the possibility of Windows Crash by the help of some learned fellows of this forum. I tried narrowing this down and for that purpose I was loitering inside the good old Control Panel.

I clicked the `Power Options`. Then I clicked `Change Plan Settings` >> `Change Advanced Power Settings`. Clicked `+` to Expand **Sleep** and then **Hibernate After**. Changed the value of `Plugged in` to 60 minutes from 15 minutes (due to which the PC was hibernating after exactly 15 minutes) and it did the job for me. Value of `On Battery` was set to 180 minutes by default(due to which the PC was not hibernating after 15 minutes while on battery).

Thank you to everyone who tried helping me out in the comments.